# Trying to do "Nmake -f Makefile.nmake verify_tools" for building wireshark

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

Does anybody know something about WireShark dissectors?

I'm trying to build WireShark with all the necessary programs installed (cygwin, python, Windows Server 2003 R2...)
But when I'm at the WireShark directory, trying to do `Nmake -f Makefile.nmake verify_tools`, all i get is: `"NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'צf'"`

Does anyone know anything about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is not specifically related to Wireshark.

Might the issue be related to character set or something ?

What happens if you try:

nmake -?      ## this should give a list of nmake options & etc

what about:

nmake /?

If nmake /?  works then maybe nmake /f Makefile.nmake might work.....